# ls command line-wrap prevention

Tags: ls

I'm looking for an answer to this question that doesn't involve the `less` command:

Is there a way to run the `ls` command in terminal, and prevent line wrapping for long filenames?

For example, upon running ls, rather than the following:

```
shortfile
thisisalongfi
lename
shortfile
```

I'd like it to cut off the long filename at the point where it would wrap, or not wrap it at all, so that it shows simply as:

```
shortfile
thisisalongfi
shortfile
```

Comment: You said you don't want to use `less` but would `ls ... | less -SEX` produce the output you expect?

Comment: Do you mean you prefer truncating ? (BTW it is neither *ls* nor your shell which commands to autowrap)

Comment: This seems to be a general question about how to avoid wrapping in a _terminal_, which the `ls` command is blissfully unaware of.  What is the issue with the names wrapping in the terminal? What terminal are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
setterm --linewrap off
ls
setterm --linewrap on
```

`setterm` will do its best to configure your terminal (terminal emulator), but in general the terminal may or may not support the feature.

Comment: This only works when writing to a terminal - which may be the OP's use case, but could be less useful in other circumstances (e.g. inserting into an Emacs buffer).

Comment: The question says "run the ls command in terminal" @TobySpeight

Answer (score 7):

The `ls` command does not have an option to truncate file names, so you'll need an extra tool.

You can use [`cut`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cut&apropos=0&sektion=1) to truncate a line. In a terminal, the environment variables `LINES` and `COLUMNS` contain the terminal dimensions.

```
ls | cut -c 1-$COLUMNS
```

This suppresses coloring from `ls` as commonly aliased. There's no easy way to combine coloring with truncation based on text tools, so if you want coloring you're better off with [telling the terminal itself to truncate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718017).

Answer (score 2):

The standard `fold(1)` command is somewhat bad here, as it can be hard to tell a wrapped filename from one that is not wrapped:

```
$ printf 'short\nlongeshort\nshort\n' | fold -w 5
short
longe
short
short
```

GNU `sed` could work, but is somewhat infested with backslashitis:

```
$ printf 'short\nlongeshort\nshort\n' | gsed 's/\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/'
short
longe
short
```

`awk` can show where the lines have been truncated:

```
$ printf 'short\nlongeshort\nshort\n' |
awk -v w=5 '{if(length > w){print substr($0,0,w-3) "..."}else{print}}'
short
lo...
short
```

Though this probably should be hidden in a script that acceots `w` width argument, or uses `$COLUMNS` by default.

Meanwhile,

```
$ setterm --linewrap off
ksh: setterm: not found
$ pkglocate setterm
$
```

is not very good for portability.

Comment: You can use `-E` with `sed` to enable enhanced regex and reduce the number of backslashes.